# Fetching individual column values instead of entities in Hibernate Pagination

Tags: hibernate, pagination

**Technology Stack :**

Spring 4

Hibernate 3

Angular 2

I am working on an application which requires pagination.
The data will be displayed in a table and the data is mostly `read only` 
We are not going to modify the data.

**My question is :**

I have read a lots of article on pagination and all are advising to use HQL and retrieve entities.

But , if I my data is READ ONLY , why do I need to retrieve entities and create an extra overhead ? Hibernate will have to manage these entities.

I will fetch only the required column values and show in table.
There will be a round trip to database at every page boundary (since there will be no caching done ) but that anyways has to happen if we are not using caching level mechanism in hibernate.

Even if we use caching , the amount of work needed to manage the cache and entries within it is definitely more than just fetching required column values.

Is this not a better design approach ? 
Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Its a subjective matter but the general rule I follow:

- Querying with DELETION/UPDATE/INSERTION => fetch entities as its trivial to manage the state and you get the benefit of the optimistic locking mechanism on top of that.
- Just querying => pagination with the use of result classes, meaning you get a ready DTO object as a result of the query.